# Spring Security Configuration access problem

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm building web application and i wannted to add logging by user name and password i done something like that at start and then add logging by pass from db.

```
package com.webservice.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationEntryPoint entrypoint;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("pass").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(entrypoint);
    }
```

Authentication entry point class looks like this

```
package com.webservice.config;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class AuthenticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint{


    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realam - " + getRealmName());
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.println("Http Status 401 " + authException.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        setRealmName("MyWebService");
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }
}
```

The app starts normally but when enter localhost line in my browse it throws instantly information from Authntication entry point and do not ask for user and password

```
Http Status 401 Full authentication is required to access this resource
```

What i should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in `Basic realm` header. Change it as shown below:

`response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm = " + getRealmName());`

It is required to encode password rather than storing it as plain text. Modify your in-memory authentication configuration as shown below:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    PasswordEncoder encoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password(encoder.encode("pass")).roles("USER");
}
```

Comment: It asks me for username and password but when i enter user and pass it throws this exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"`

Comment: @DanielAvoyan - storing passwords in plain text is a bad idea. So spring security makes it mandatory to use a password encoder and encode the password before storing it (either in-memory or an external database).